# What CSS would get two buttons to line up, respectively, on the left and right side of a 3-colspan table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>short text</td>
    <td>long long long text</td>
    <td>short text</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan='3'>
      <button id='leftbutton'/>
      <button id='rightbutton'/>
   </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

What CSS styles should I apply to get my buttons to lay out like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|short text       |      long long long text     |  short text  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| button left     |                              | button right |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

instead of their current layout:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|short text       |      long long long text     |  short text  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|button left|button right|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd use CSS to do this. Since you're using tables for layout, then you should do this the "table" way. Put each button into a different `<td>` element, and give the first one a `colspan` of `2`.

Answer (score 4):

This outta do it:

```
#leftbutton { float: left; }
#rightbutton { float: right; }
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KvWT2/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `#rightbutton { float: right; }`?

Edit: hunter beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

float:left and float:right

you can use inline css for this: 
 and

heres a tutorial: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/